# RDBMS result caching vs Application level caching?

Tags: java, web-applications, memcached, ehcache, rdbms

In 10 years of mine experience, we used RDBMS either Oracle or SQL server with configuration by default. Never tuned the result cache which is disabled by default(at least in oracle).I have always seen using the cache options at application level like ehcache/memcache/redis etc as caching solution.

Question - Is it not a great option to use the result cache i.e. DB level proactively whether or not I face any performance issue provided I have memory bandwidth available on DB server ?
with this query results say `select * from employee where department = 'Finance'`  will always be cached corresponding to finance department.

My question is why not use DB level caching if hardware can support it with LRU or appropriate algo per specific requirement instead
of application level caching where I need to create keys, deploy it(like memcached) as separate server ?

Comment: My general rule:  Don't cache a cache.  A database will do all sorts of caching; one rarely needs to add another layer of caching.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Application level caching that [ehcache](http://www.ehcache.org), for example, provides you with, allows your application to not pay the price of fetching data over the network. (supposing that your application is not hosted on the same machine as your RDBMS)

When you think about, [looking at the common latency in IT systems](https://gist.github.com/jboner/2841832), it's probably already a huge gain for your app.

Comment: Agreed. Point here  is use both `EHcache(for objects which I already will be needing frequently and costly to fetch fromDB ) `and `DB cache(for db objects which may or may not be costly or usage will depend on work flow)`.  Point I am trying to make here why not configure DB cache to some large value with LRU so that some of the query results(whether they are costly or not) can be fetched from memory instead of IO call . At least it will make some difference for sure if not big

Comment: Yes, I suppose that makes sense what you're describing. But it also sounds like you end up with 2 caches to configure and remember about ...